# Tomcat: Wrong Image

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have a pretty bad example of a heisenbug:

Every now and then tomcat delivers a wrong image. Instead of an asteriks it delifers some image a user uploaded.

In the rendered HTML file the img-src points to the correct url.

Does anybody have pointer where to start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - could be a race condition.  If those images are shared state in a servlet, perhaps access isn't synchronized properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost guaranteed to be there is not enough information in the img-src attribute to obtain the image by itself.

Making hte code work without that constraint is going to be so much of a headache you will have an easier time putting everything needed to construct the image in its img-src.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by putting everything needed to construct the image? Do you mean the URL of the image? But when that's the problem, why does it work most of the time?

Comment: You probably have set some variables in the main HTML page that are read by the image page. That doesn't work but appears to work most of the time.

Comment: There's no image page, just a static gif file. Sometimes not this gif file is displayed. Maybe I'm just a little bit slow but I don't get what you mean with "image page".

Comment: Sorry it sounded to me more like a generated image.